# How to override Jenkins user-defined variable during runtime?

Tags: git, powershell, variables, jenkins, devops

I am trying to get the email id of the user who committed the changes into bitbucket from Jenkins. I have a user-defined variable named `EMAIL_ID` which has the default value `example1@gmail.com`. Using web-hook I trigger the Jenkins job. The Jenkins job has the following PowerShell script for finding the email id of the user who committed into bitbucket:

```
git log -n 1 > git.log
$var = Select-String -Path .\git.log -Pattern "@gmail.com"
$regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@gmail.com"
$email = [regex]::matches($var, $regex).value
$ENV:EMAIL_ID=$email
```

When I echo the `$email`, I get `example2@gmail.com`. But the scope of this variable is within this script only. Even if I assign `$ENV:EMAIL_ID=$email`, its not working as expected. I need to access this variable from other build steps in the same job. In other words I need to make this variable as a global one, so I can access this from anywhere within the job. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two points here: first, you create the PowerShell script that returns the information that you want (in this case, the email address)

**I'd assume you are using pipelines** - In that case, what you need is to call the `bat` step in pipeline using the option `returnStdout: true` (see doc [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/)) and assign the "printed" information to a variable in the pipeline.

For possible following issues, you can have a look into
[Jenkinsfile windows cmd output variable reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329493/jenkinsfile-windows-cmd-output-variable-reference) and [How do you handle global variables in a declarative pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716933/how-do-you-handle-global-variables-in-a-declarative-pipeline)

Comment: Thanks! This helped me! But can we achieve the same in free style job?

Comment: I have not tested it, but you can call Groovy scripts in free style jobs. But if that does not work, you can write the email address into a file. Read that file from the next steps should work (this is the solution I used in freestyle jobs)